# VLD causes issues

Tags: memory-leaks, visual-studio-2017

ALL,

I have MSVC 2017 Community and trying to find where is the memory leak in my program.

I did compile and link against the VLD and I did copy vld_x86.dll, dbghelp.dll and Microsoft.DTfW.DHL.manifest to the same place where executable is.

Trying to run the program under MSVC I am getting

```
wntdll.pdb not loaded
```

exception.

If I build without VLD, program starts without any issues.

What is a way to debug memory leaks with MSVC?

TIA!!

Comment: well, debugging memory leaks is hard. do you have the original source code? if i remember correctly visual studio should have [built in profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2015) and we can leverage that.. i have no idea why you need to copy those dll...

Comment: @BagusTesa, 1.profiler is used for performance tuning and not for the memory leaks. 2. Source code is all mine. 3. For MSVC the library you link against has to be accessible thru the $PATH. The easiest way to achieve it is to copy the dlls to where the executable is.